# joomla user authentication by my own custom written form inputs

Tags: authentication, joomla

I've been struggling to find out about user authentication using your own form elements.

In order to make it clear, heres what i want to do.

I'm going to have a button which is going to redirect to a page.
Now, this page can be redirected to in the following ways.

A popup opens where the user needs to enter their email address and password.
   My form is like this

```
    <form action="userlogin.php" method="post">
    <ul>Email
        <li><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>Password
        <li><input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" /> </li>
    </ul>

    </form>
```

The user clicks the submit button and if the email address and password exist then we have a successful login and if they dont then we add that user in the database and then redirect.

I dont understand how to authenticate user login using this form i've mentioned about. Which file do i have to post it to and how can it work like a normal joomla login.

Please do help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own authentication routine relatively easily in two steps.

- Authentication Logic

For the authentication logic, in the plugins folder, there is another folder called "authentication".  Aside from the default joomla authentication, there is another called "example.php", which you can clone and work on from there.  These are the plugins that you can enable/disable in the plugins manager in your Joomla Administrator, so you can look at them and see the different ways that they authenicate (gmail, openid, etc.).

Be sure to scan/replace all the naming used in the copied file (it's not very big), and when you're happy with it, make an entry in table jos_plugins so that you can enable it in the Joomla administrator.

- Your Form (using template *atomic* as the example, and assuming you're using mod_login)

Within /templates/atomic/html/mod_login you should have, a file called default.php.  This is where you change the form to suit your needs, and incorporate into the authentication logic your wrote in the plugin.

- Popup Approach

That will depend on the template you're using, and how it, or you, generally handle popups.  [Rockettheme](http://www.rockettheme.com/) have many popup modules (some being free) which demonstrate how you could do it that way, or jquery if you're comfortable with that, the list goes on....

Answer (score 0):

You could override the existing login form and open this in a modal popup?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit about that? I'm notaware of how to override forms and stuff in joomla.
Thanks.

Comment: There are lots of tutorials out there (and forum posts http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=629&t=710732) but in a nut shell. Look in your templates/yourtemplate/html folder. You should see some existing overrides. You can duplicate the com_users/views/login into the templates/html folder and modify it there. To open in a popup, simply add the class="modal" to the link to the login page and ensure that Mootools is being loaded. http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core